# Convert an array to a one channel image

Tags: objective-c, arrays, image, channel

I am an Xcode beginner and I am working on a project where I have to convert a `float[x][y]` array to a one channel (grayscale) image. Then create a method that convert this image back to a `float[x][y];`
Any help help on the subject is appreciated, and please, if possible, detail your answer as much as possible.
Thank You in advance

update 1:
the x and y are the coordiantes of the row and line. 
The float is the value of the pixel between 0 and 1 (of course a pixel value is an int between 0 and 255 for 8 bit);
A black and white image has a values of either 0 or 1 not in between while a grayscale has values between 0 and 1, but both images should be a one channel image since we do not need the R G B and alfa, just for one channel is enough

update 2:
I have no clue how to recreate the image from the float table but what I was able to find is how to turn a 4 8bit channel image into a float table but I was hoping to find a more efficient way and is more faster and I am not sure this one will work with one channel image:

```
/////////////////////
CGImageRef imageRef = [FilteredImage CGImage];

    int lenght = width*height;

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    unsigned char *rawData = (unsigned char*) calloc(height * width * 4, sizeof(unsigned char));
    NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
    NSUInteger bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width;
    NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData, width, height, bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);

    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageRef);
    CGContextRelease(context);

    // Now your rawData contains the image data in the RGBA8888 pixel format.

    int byteIndex = 0;

    for (int i = 0 ; i < lenght ; ++i)

    {
        int X=0,Y=0;
        CGFloat red   = (rawData[byteIndex]     * 1.0) / 255.0;
        CGFloat green = (rawData[byteIndex + 1] * 1.0) / 255.0;
        CGFloat blue  = (rawData[byteIndex + 2] * 1.0) / 255.0;
//      CGFloat alpha = (rawData[byteIndex + 3] * 1.0) / 255.0;
        float grayscale = ( red + green + blue )/3;
        GrayscaleArray[Y][X] = grayscale;
        X++;
        if( X == width )
            Y++;
        byteIndex += 4;

    }
    free(rawData);

//////////////////////
```

Comment: Is your original image RGB (e.g., is there a red, green, and blue value for each X,Y pixel)?

Comment: @Rogier The OP has a two-dimensional array of float values. Each float value represents the grayscale at that coordinate.

Comment: @JosephAzzam You need to post what you have tried so far. At least do some research and post what ideas you have. This site is not for spoon feeding you complete solutions. Hint - look into Core Graphics.

Comment: @mattnedrich there is no original image, the original is float**

Comment: @rmaddy please note that I have been trying to solve this for the last 2 weeks and I do is hitting walls and dead ends, like I said I am a beginner, anyway I posted what I came up with so far at least what my research led me 2

Comment: What you're saying suggests you should try less hard problems first. Driving a T80 comes after driving a bicycle. Unless you're in Soviet Russia, in which case it might be easier to drive a tank anyway...

Comment: The poster should first learn programming in Objective-C, get acquainted with Apple' APIs (Core Graphics, most appropriately here), and then he might be able to ask a better question, or solve it himself.

Answer (score 3):

```
/////////////////////////
unsigned int *pixels = (unsigned int *)malloc(width * height * 4);
memcpy(pixels, buffer, width * height * 4);

CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, pixels, width * height * 4, NULL);
CGImageRef cgImage = CGImageCreate(width, height, 8, 32, width * 4, colorSpace,   kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big, provider, NULL, false, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];
//////////////////////////
```

The opposite convert maybe

1:change the RGB image into gray image.

2:save data from image.

```
-(UIImage*)getGrayImage:(UIImage*)sourceImage   
{   
int width = sourceImage.size.width;   
int height = sourceImage.size.height;   
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();   
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate (nil,width,height,8,0,colorSpace,kCGImageAlphaNone);   
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);   
if (context == NULL) {   
    return nil;   
}   
CGContextDrawImage(context,CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), sourceImage.CGImage);   
UIImage *grayImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context)];   
CGContextRelease(context);   
return grayImage;   
}  


NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(grayImage); 
Byte *testByte = (Byte *)[testData bytes];
```

I don't have a validation program feasibility, but hope to be able to help you!